# Exercise about an algebraic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratics, projective-geometry

Let $\mathbb{P}^6$ the six-dimensional complex projective space. Suppose that $Q_{i}$ is a smooth quadric in $\mathbb{P}^6$ for $i=1,...,4$. Define $$S=Q_1 \cap Q_2 \cap Q_3 \cap Q_4 $$ as complete intersection of four quadric. So, by definition, $S$ is a smooth algebraic surface in $\mathbb{P}^6$.  Let $H$ an hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^6$. Put $C=S \cap H$.
Question:
How can i compute all numerical invariant of the surface $S$ i.e. $K_S^2$, $\chi(O_S)$, $p_g$, $q$ and so on ?
is there a formula to compute $g=g(C)$?

Comment: Is the intersection of four smooth quadrics in $P^6$ automatically smooth?

Comment: yes i suppose the quadrics to be smooth

Comment: @dario : You did not answer Mariano's question

Comment: The quadrics may be smooth, dario, but it doesn't follow that $S$ is smooth.  I think you want to say that $S$ is a complete intersection of the $Q_i$.

Comment: Yes. that is the assumption.

Answer (score 3):

For (2), use adjunction formula and get 
\begin{eqnarray}
K_S=i^*_S(K_{\mathbb{P}^6}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^6}(2)^{\otimes 4})=i_S^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^6}(-7)\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^6}(2)^{\otimes 4})=\mathcal{O}_S(1)
\end{eqnarray}
Relation between $K_S$ and $K_C$ can also be obtained using adjunction formula.

Comment: how can i compute the pluri genus $p_g$ and the irregurality $q$ of $S$ where $g$ is the genus of $C$?